# Inconsistent results with predict_proba

Tags: python, flask, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm working on creating a stroke prediction Flask API using logistic regression.

I've built my model on PyCharm and my classification based on predict_proba are well distributed when I run it regularly (a pretty equal number of low/moderate/high risk classifications).
Here is a bit of my model for context:

```
df_features = {'age',
               'hypertension',
               'heart_disease',
               'ever_married',
               'Residence_type',
               'avg_glucose_level',
               'bmi',
               'gender',
               'work_type',
               'smoking_status'}

df_target = ['stroke']
x = df[df_features]
y = df[df_target]

x_smote, y_smote = smote.fit_resample(x, y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_smote, y_smote, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
x_valid, x_test, y_valid, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
md.fit(x_test, y_test.values.ravel())

pickle.dump(md, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

When trying to deploy onto Flask, I encountered an issue where almost all my inputs are being classified as Low Risk.
Looking back at my model, I discovered that for some reason when I pass an set of values directly through the model, the results look very different from previous results.

```
print(md.predict_proba(x_test))
```

will generate these predictions:

```
[[0.81931953 0.18068047]
 [0.96735583 0.03264417]
 [0.96280228 0.03719772]
 ...
 [0.50304004 0.49695996]
 [0.41301474 0.58698526]
 [0.82213934 0.17786066]]
```

As for when I try passing a specific array,

```
print(md.predict_proba([[50, 1, 0, 0, 1, 105.32, 32.6, 0, 0, 1]]))
```

will generate results like this:

```
[1.00000000e+00 2.24494636e-16]
```

I tried running it on Google Collab as well and the same command is giving me proper results so I'm stumped.
Can anyone explain why this is? Because in the API, I split the results and use the [0] value of predict_proba to classify the risk but my results are all over the place.

I created a pipeline and ran the following test:

```
input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[50, 1, 0, 0, 1, 105.32, 32.6, 0, 0, 1]],
                               columns=headers,
                               dtype=float,
                               index=['input'])
prediction = pipe.predict(input_variables)
print("Prediction: ", prediction)
prediction_probab = pipe.predict_proba(input_variables)
print("Probabilities: ", prediction_probab)
```

And got this as a result:

```
Prediction:  [0]
Probabilities:  [[1.00000000e+00 3.64844539e-61]]
```

Comment: Please provide more details: First show a few examples from the test set and the results you get with those. If that does not reveal the issue try to show minimal but complete (i.e. reproducible for everyone) examples how you do the prediction on the test set and in the API. (We need to know how you train/load the model and what you actually put in...)

Comment: @MB-F I've tried adding in some more details, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: There are two models in the training snippet (`sc` and `md`) but only one `model` in the API... did you forget to transform the features?

Comment: @MB-F  `sc` is StandardScaler that I used to standardize `x_train` and `x_test` whereas `md` is my LogReg model (and the only model I used). So when I fit my model, it should have transformed. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

When `sc` is a StandardScaler and `md` is the classification model, the model is trained with standardized features.

```
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
md.fit(x_test, y_test.values.ravel())
```

That's good practice. However, the model, as stored above, does not know anything about the scaler! It only knows that its features are within a certain range.

Now, when you do `md.predict_proba([[50, 1, 0, 0, 1, 105.32, 32.6, 0, 0, 1]])` you pass raw (unstandardized) features to the model, which are far outside of the standardized range the model has learned. Instead, you need to apply the scaler:

```
x_real = sc.transform([[50, 1, 0, 0, 1, 105.32, 32.6, 0, 0, 1]])
result = md.predict_proba(x_real)
```

You need to do that in the API too.

Solution 1: store both `sc` and `md` in a pickle file or separate pickle files, load and apply both in the API. This has the drawback that the API is tightly coupled to your model structure (if you want to add another processing step, you'd need to change the API code).

Solution 2: put scaler and model into a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html), which you can treat as a single model when storing/loading/applying.

Comment: That makes complete sense but unfortunately I'm getting the same results for some reason. I created a pipeline with standardscaler and logisticregression, fitted it with `pipe.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())`, and then pickled it.. When I tried to run it through my API, I'm still getting the same results (consistant 'Low stroke', and results like `[1.00000000e+00 2.24494636e-16]`